# The argument type 'TimeOfDay' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'DateTime'

Tags: flutter, dart

```
ListTile(
  leading: Icon(Icons.access_time),
  onTap: () async {
    final TimeOfDay? picked = await showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialTime: _time,
    );
    if (picked != null) {
      setState(() {
        _eventTime.text = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(picked);
      });
    }
  },
  title: TextField(
    readOnly: true,
    controller: _eventTime,
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      border: OutlineInputBorder(),
      labelText: "Event Time",
    ),
  ),
),
```

I want to store the value of the selected time in the controller (_eventtime) to save in the firestore database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change mapping.

Change:

```
_eventTime.text = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(picked);
```

to:

```
_eventTime.text = DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, picked.hour, picked.minute));
```

Comment: _eventTime.text =
                              DateFormat('HH:mm').format(DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day, picked.hour, picked.minute));

it did fix the error but the textfield is still showing only   00:00

Comment: Try check values in picked. For temporary do _eventTime.text = "${picked.hour} ${picked.minute}" and check those values